# Primefaces confirmDialog with EL variables and in modal Window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I have a strange problem with Primefaces' confirm Dialog.
What I need is a confirmation dialog that displays some variables im my Bean, working in a modal dialog window and firing a Bean method. But it seems I can't get the 3... :-(

Here is what I've been trying:

```
    <p:confirmDialog header="Aviso de Confirmação"
        closable="false"
        appendToBody="true"
        global="false"
        showEffect="fade"
        hideEffect="fade"           
        widgetVar="confirmDlg">
        <h:form>
            <f:facet name="message">
                <h:outputText value="Confirma o registro de desistência do candidato(a) #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.inscricao} - #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.papelPessoa.pessoaFisica.nomeCompleto}?" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                icon="ui-icon-check" 
                action="#{registrosCandidatoBean.gravarDesistencia()}"
                update=":formDesistencia :formMensagem:mensagemFixa"
                ajax="false" 
                immediate="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Não" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                onclick="confirmDlg.hide();" />
        </h:form>
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

*** This one displays the message and calls the method. But the "message" in f:facet is not displayed. Id I use the normal "message" attribute, It doesn't use the variables in my bean.

```
    <p:confirmDialog header="Aviso de Confirmação"
        closable="false"
        appendToBody="true"
        global="false"
        showEffect="fade"
        hideEffect="fade"
        widgetVar="confirmDlg">
            <f:facet name="message">
                <h:outputText value="Confirma o registro de desistência do candidato(a) #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.inscricao} - #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.papelPessoa.pessoaFisica.nomeCompleto}?" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                icon="ui-icon-check" 
                action="#{registrosCandidatoBean.gravarDesistencia()}"
                update=":formDesistencia :formMensagem:mensagemFixa"
                ajax="false" 
                immediate="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Não" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                onclick="confirmDlg.hide();" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

*** This one displays the message and "message" in f:facet. But any Bean methods aren't called.

```
    <p:confirmDialog header="Aviso de Confirmação"
        closable="false"
        global="false"
        showEffect="fade"
        hideEffect="fade"
        widgetVar="confirmDlg">
            <f:facet name="message">
                <h:outputText value="Confirma o registro de desistência do candidato(a) #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.inscricao} - #{registrosCandidatoBean.candidatoInclusaoDesistencia.papelPessoa.pessoaFisica.nomeCompleto}?" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
                icon="ui-icon-check" 
                action="#{registrosCandidatoBean.gravarDesistencia()}"
                update=":formDesistencia :formMensagem:mensagemFixa"
                ajax="false" 
                immediate="true" />
            <p:commandButton value="Não" 
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                icon="ui-icon-close" 
                onclick="confirmDlg.hide();" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

*** This one displays the message and "message" in f:facet. Apparently it calls the Bean methods, but I can't test it since the dialog is greyed and I can't click the buttons.

Can it work the way I need?

Primefaces 4.0

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

for the third scenario, try adding;

> appendTo="@(body)"